# Removing "Chapter 0" before TOC and Appendix issue

Tags: header-footer, memoir, fancyhdr

I am using the `memoir` class with the `fancyhdr` package for headings. I wanted to lower the size of my headings because of overlapping issues. Here is my tex code

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\setlength\midchapskip{10pt}
\makechapterstyle{VZ23}{
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\chapnumfont{\Huge\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\Huge\scshape\centering}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{%
\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{%
\vphantom{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
}\chapterstyle{VZ23}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\itshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{\itshape \nouppercase Chapter \arabic{chapter}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{abstract}

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Extremely long first section that overlaps}
\newpage
\section{Extremely long second section that overlaps}

\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}
\section{Lipsum}
\newpage
\section{Lipsum}

\end{document}
```

This works well but I got two remaining issues :

- At the beginning of my document (before first chapter and toc) I got a annoying "Chapter 0" heading
- I would like to write "Appendix" instead of "Chapter" when hitting chapters after `\appendix`

Answer (score 3):

When you run your code you get the following error message;

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \footruleskip already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

and this is because you are using the `fancyhdr` package to produce your headings instead of using the built-in commands offered by the class. To remove the error and to get rid of the problem mentioned in the question, use the mechanism provided by `memoir` and described in the Section **7.3 MAKING HEADERS AND FOOTERS** of the `memoir` manual.

You declared the `oneside` class option, but this option is not compatible with the way you were defining your headers; here's a modification of the original code that you can adapt according to your needs:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}

\setlength\midchapskip{10pt}
\makechapterstyle{VZ23}{
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\chapnumfont{\Huge\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\Huge\scshape\centering}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{%
\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{%
\vphantom{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
\par\nobreak\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}
}
\chapterstyle{VZ23}

\usepackage{geometry}

\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\itshape\rightmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Extremely long first section that overlaps}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was definitely doing it wrong. By the way I want to keep the oneside option. When I switch I get nothing except when using `\rightmark` in `\makeoddhead` which is pretty weird. Any ideas to fix this as well ?